# Pandas Merge Resample Result for Missing Rows

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

Note: I asked a worse version of this yesterday, which I quickly deleted. However @FlorianGD left a comment which gave me the answer I needed - so I've added this up in any case with the solution he advised.

### Prepare Start Dataframe

I have some dates:

```
date_dict = {0: '1/31/2010',
 1: '12/15/2009',
 2: '3/19/2010',
 3: '10/25/2009',
 4: '1/17/2009',
 5: '9/4/2009',
 6: '2/21/2010',
 7: '8/30/2009',
 8: '1/31/2010',
 9: '11/30/2008',
 10: '2/8/2009',
 11: '4/9/2010',
 12: '9/13/2009',
 13: '10/19/2009',
 14: '1/24/2010',
 15: '3/8/2009',
 16: '11/30/2008',
 17: '7/30/2009',
 18: '12/12/2009',
 19: '3/8/2009',
 20: '6/18/2010',
 21: '11/30/2008',
 22: '12/30/2009',
 23: '10/28/2009',
 24: '1/28/2010'}
```

Convert to dataframe and `datetime` format:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame(list(date_dict.items()), columns=['Ind', 'Game_date'])
df['Date'] = df['Game_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.strip(), "%m/%d/%Y"))
df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
del df['Ind'], df['Game_date']
df['Count'] = 1

df
         Date
0  2008-11-30
1  2008-11-30
2  2008-11-30
3  2009-01-17
4  2009-02-08
5  2009-03-08
6  2009-03-08
7  2009-07-30
8  2009-08-30
9  2009-09-04
10 2009-09-13
11 2009-10-19
12 2009-10-25
13 2009-10-28
14 2009-12-12
15 2009-12-15
16 2009-12-30
17 2010-01-24
18 2010-01-28
19 2010-01-31
20 2010-01-31
21 2010-02-21
22 2010-03-19
23 2010-04-09
24 2010-06-18
```

Now what I want to do is to resample this dataframe to group rows into groups of weeks, and return the information to the original dataframe.

### 2 Use `resample()` to group for each week and return count

I perform a resample for each week every Tuesday:

```
c_index = df.set_index('Date', drop=True).resample('1W-TUE').sum()['Count'].reset_index()
c_index.dropna(subset=['Count'], axis=0, inplace=True)
c_index = c_index.reset_index(drop=True)
c_index['Index_Col'] = c_index.index + 1

c_index
         Date  Count  Index_Col
0  2008-12-02    3.0          1
1  2009-01-20    1.0          2
2  2009-02-10    1.0          3
3  2009-03-10    2.0          4
4  2009-08-04    1.0          5
5  2009-09-01    1.0          6
6  2009-09-08    1.0          7
7  2009-09-15    1.0          8
8  2009-10-20    1.0          9
9  2009-10-27    1.0         10
10 2009-11-03    1.0         11
11 2009-12-15    2.0         12
12 2010-01-05    1.0         13
13 2010-01-26    1.0         14
14 2010-02-02    3.0         15
15 2010-02-23    1.0         16
16 2010-03-23    1.0         17
17 2010-04-13    1.0         18
18 2010-06-22    1.0         19
```

This shows the number of rows in `df` that fall within each week in `c_index`, so, for week `2008-12-02` there were 3 rows that fell in this week.

### Broadcast Information back to original `df`

Now, I want to merge those columns back onto the original `df`, *essentially broadcasting the grouped data onto the individual rows.*

This should give:

```
    Date        Count_Raw       Count_Total     Index_Col
0   2008-11-30          1           3           1
1   2008-11-30          1           3           1
2   2008-11-30          1           3           1
3   2009-01-17          1           1           2
4   2009-02-08          1           1           3
5   2009-03-08          1           2           4
6   2009-03-08          1           2           4
7   2009-07-30          1           1           5
8   2009-08-30          1           1           6
9   2009-09-04          1           1           7
10  2009-09-13          1           1           8
11  2009-10-19          1           1           9
12  2009-10-25          1           1           10
13  2009-10-28          1           1           11
14  2009-12-12          1           2           12
15  2009-12-15          1           2           12
16  2009-12-30          1           1           13
17  2010-01-24          1           1           14
18  2010-01-28          1           3           15
19  2010-01-31          1           3           15
20  2010-01-31          1           3           15
21  2010-02-21          1           1           16
22  2010-03-19          1           1           17
23  2010-04-09          1           1           18
24  2010-06-18          1           1           19
```

So the `Count_Total` represents the total number in that group, and `Index_Col` tracks the order of the groups.

For example, in this case, the group info for `2010-02-02` has been assigned to `2010-01-28`, `2010-01-31`, and `2010-01-31`.

To do this I have tried the following:

**Failed attempt**

```
df.merge(c_index, on='Date', how='left', suffixes=('_Raw', '_Total'))
         Date  Count_Raw  Count_Total  Index_Col
0  2008-11-30          1          NaN        NaN
1  2008-11-30          1          NaN        NaN
2  2008-11-30          1          NaN        NaN
3  2009-01-17          1          NaN        NaN
4  2009-02-08          1          NaN        NaN
5  2009-03-08          1          NaN        NaN
6  2009-03-08          1          NaN        NaN
7  2009-07-30          1          NaN        NaN
8  2009-08-30          1          NaN        NaN
9  2009-09-04          1          NaN        NaN
10 2009-09-13          1          NaN        NaN
11 2009-10-19          1          NaN        NaN
12 2009-10-25          1          NaN        NaN
13 2009-10-28          1          NaN        NaN
14 2009-12-12          1          NaN        NaN
15 2009-12-15          1          2.0       12.0
16 2009-12-30          1          NaN        NaN
17 2010-01-24          1          NaN        NaN
18 2010-01-28          1          NaN        NaN
19 2010-01-31          1          NaN        NaN
20 2010-01-31          1          NaN        NaN
21 2010-02-21          1          NaN        NaN
22 2010-03-19          1          NaN        NaN
23 2010-04-09          1          NaN        NaN
24 2010-06-18          1          NaN        NaN
```

Reasons for failure: This merges the two dataframes *only when the date in `c_index` is also present in `df`*. In this example the only week that has had information added is 2009-12-15 as this is the only date common across both dataframes.

How can I do a better merge to get what I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @FlorianGD, this can be achieved using [pandas.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) with the `direction='forward'` argument:

```
pd.merge_asof(left=df, right=c_index, on='Date', suffixes=('_Raw', '_Total'), direction='forward')

         Date  Count_Raw  Count_Total  Index_Col
0  2008-11-30          1          3.0          1
1  2008-11-30          1          3.0          1
2  2008-11-30          1          3.0          1
3  2009-01-17          1          1.0          2
4  2009-02-08          1          1.0          3
5  2009-03-08          1          2.0          4
6  2009-03-08          1          2.0          4
7  2009-07-30          1          1.0          5
8  2009-08-30          1          1.0          6
9  2009-09-04          1          1.0          7
10 2009-09-13          1          1.0          8
11 2009-10-19          1          1.0          9
12 2009-10-25          1          1.0         10
13 2009-10-28          1          1.0         11
14 2009-12-12          1          2.0         12
15 2009-12-15          1          2.0         12
16 2009-12-30          1          1.0         13
17 2010-01-24          1          1.0         14
18 2010-01-28          1          3.0         15
19 2010-01-31          1          3.0         15
20 2010-01-31          1          3.0         15
21 2010-02-21          1          1.0         16
22 2010-03-19          1          1.0         17
23 2010-04-09          1          1.0         18
24 2010-06-18          1          1.0         19
```